# webview not caching

Tags: android, webview

I have been trying to enable caching in Android WebView but every config I saw on SO ends in failure.

Here is what I have:

I have a webpage which has an Iframe inside that loads 10-12 pages in a loop all the content in those pages have `Cache-Control: max-age=86400` header.

If I load these pages normally in a browser they work and the pages are cached.

So here is the config that I have

```
        getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        getSettings().setAppCachePath(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
```

These settings work for media playback and enabling js

**EDIT**

I built a new app and tried loading google with the `loadUrl` method and reloaded that with a button while the net was off, it was able to reload the page without internet it means it cached that page.

So the issue is that webview is not caching pages which are being loaded by the page.

If anyone knows how we can cache the content which is loaded by webview page loads it would be a great help.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a series of detailed tests on our iframe and Android device, I came to realize that WebView does not cache files which are bigger than a particular size.

One of my pages which were being loaded by the iframe had a video of 30mb which was not getting cached and was resulting in huge data consumption. (as it was getting rendered every 2 mins)

I reduced it to 10mb and it still did not cache it finally I reduced it to 980kb and it started caching.

I am not sure about the caching limit per file for WebView but I came across an interesting bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=323871) which states after Android 4.3 the total cache limit was hardcoded to 20mb which we can find in this [file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/jb-mr2-release/Source/WebKit/android/WebCoreSupport/WebCache.cpp) on line 98.

If anyone knows where these limits are documented do let the community know by replying here.

Comment: So is your answer to reduce file size? What if that isn't an option, did you find an alternative?

Comment: @c_rueschenberg if that's the case then you have to rebuild chromium after changing the hard limit set in the source files and use that build. Check the file link in my answer which shows the hard limit.

Answer (score 1):

This code solve my problem, hope help you too:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

**EDIT:** Also you don't needs to these lines:

```
getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);

 getSettings().setAppCachePath(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
```

Remove them and check one more time. `AppCache` setting not related to type of cache that you want.

Comment: will do... one more thing I am using android 5... does it make any difference in the config?

Comment: The problem that I'm facing with this LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK is that if an internet connection is present then it is not using cache irrespective of cache existence.